# Python Timing Out: WARNING:root:SKIPPED (taking more than 30 seconds)

Tags: python, performance, warnings

Does anyone have any documentation on how to adjust the timing out issue for Python?

I'm running fairly large code to match distributions to a lot of data (about 2900 distributions total) and of the 8 defined curves, 3 of them often time out and give me the following error:

- WARNING:root:SKIPPED erlang distribution (taking more than 30 seconds)
- WARNING:root:SKIPPED rayleigh distribution (taking more than 30 seconds)
- WARNING:root:SKIPPED gamma distribution (taking more than 30 seconds)

I'm worried since it is skipping these three distributions, the code is not giving me accurate distributions for my data.

Is there a way to fix the 30 second issue?

Comment: This is not a python issue, this is an issue with whatever library you're using.